# Rename a dynamic folder in Windows using batch script

Tags: windows, script, batch

```
C:\Users\xxxx\Downloads\CarepointServiceR2_CarepointServiceR2_**109**_artifacts
```

The Number which is highlighted is dynamically changed each and every day. I have to rename this like CarePointServiceR2.

I Use this:

```
ren C:\Users\xxxx\Downloads\CarepointServiceR2_CarepointServiceR2_???_artifacts CarePointServicesR2
```

It was not working. Please help me to get out of this.

Comment: Can you define what you mean by not working? Is it throwing an error, renaming the wrong thing, not renaming? Crashing?

Answer (score 1):

The `*` is *also* a wild card

The following should help (assuming that since the name changes each day that it is the only file in the folder - if there are multiple files with different numbers, this won't work).

```
ren C:\Users\xxxx\Downloads\CarepointServiceR2_CarepointServiceR2_*_artifacts CarePointServicesR2
```

[More reading about wild cards](http://www.computerhope.com/jargon/w/wildcard.htm)

Comment: In theory, his original `???` should have worked too.

Comment: @Bob, yes, I agree, although possibly dangerous when (if) that numbers hits NNNN characters (such as 1000)